# F# : wrap tuples into multiple lines

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code, ionide

Let's say I have a simple `Tree` :

```
type Tree =
    | BinaryNode of Tree * int * Tree
    | Tip 

    member this.Sum =
        match this with
        | Tip -> 0
        | BinaryNode(left, value, right) -> left.Sum + value + right.Sum
```

and I define a tree by :

```
let tree = BinaryNode( BinaryNode( Tip, 2, Tip ), 1, BinaryNode( Tip, 3, Tip ))
```

But I think it's really hard to read if we have a tree with multiple nodes. So I wrap it into multiple lines as below :

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

    let tree = 
        BinaryNode( 
            BinaryNode( Tip, 2, Tip ), 
            1, 
            BinaryNode( Tip, 3, Tip )
        )

    printf "%A" (tree.Sum)

    0
```

The above code works as expected in `Visual Studio`. But when I use `Visual Studio Code` with [`Ionide`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ionide.Ionide-fsharp) , it reminds me that :

> Lint: Comma in tuple instantiation should be followed by single space.

[image]

**My question :**

1. I'm confused. Is it bad to wrap tuples into multiple lines ?
2. If not, how to make the lint shut up ?
3. If the answer is Yes, how to improve the readability when we have ten nodes ?

Comment: Since this is a only _should_ hint, I'd say ignore it, however it would probably be useful to be able to disable this specific suggestion in highlighting. Have you tried it in F# interactive in VS? Maybe the question is more about consistent highlighting in the various products than an actual "best practice" issue.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel Does that mean it's fine to wrap into multiple lines in that way?  I'm asking this because I met a question online that the OP used an indent and `{}` that is not considered as best practice and then encountered an unexpected error.  As a newbie,  the indent and space in F# is really confusing for me.

Comment: [Update]: Seems that the same code runs without any unnecessary "suggestion" today (`Ionide(v3.37.0)` )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It don't think it's necessarily bad to do. Well, I hope not, since I do it all the time. Especially in cases like this, where the line would otherwise be much too wide, to be pleasent to read.

As far as I can tell, Ionide uses FSharpLint. According to [the docs](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpLint), individual warnings can be disabled on a project level, by placing an XML file called `Settings.FSharpLint` in the project folder, with the desired configuration.

I think, in your case, the file should have the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FSharpLintSettings>
  <Analysers>
    <TupleCommaSpacing>
      <Enabled>false</Enabled>
    </TupleCommaSpacing>
  </Analysers>
</FSharpLintSettings>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer: is there a way to disable Lint only on a local level ? For example, if I can make sure it's safe , is there a way to make it shut up for only some lines ? something like `#safe{ .... }`? . I think that's better than disable the Lint on a project level

Comment: That might be possible using the `SuppressMessage` attribute, but I'm not entirely sure on which granularity. Have a look at the documentation page here: http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpLint/

Comment: But if I add a `[<SuppressMessage>]` on `let tree = ...`, it complains that `Unexpected symbol '[<' in binding`.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Perhaps you need to add the attribute to the outermost binding - in your case the `main` function.

Comment: But in that way other bad formatting will be suppressed too.

Comment: If you just add `[<SuppressMessage>]`, then yes, I suppose so. But as is stated in the docs, you should be able to do `[<SuppressMessage("Formatting","TupleCommaSpacing")>]`, to suppress only the desired warning